# File import using Angular prime ng issue

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I am working on file import feature in Angular. From the postman I am able to make request correctly but from Angular I am getting an error. Please correct me what I am doing wrong.

Angular code (Prime Ng)

```
<p-fileUpload mode="basic" name="demo[]" url="https://gateway.xxx.intra/file"  maxFileSize="1000000" (onUpload)="onBasicUpload($event)" auto="true">
```

Response from server

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/usr/src/gateway/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:158:10)
    at parse (/usr/src/gateway/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /usr/src/gateway/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/usr/src/gateway/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/usr/src/gateway/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/usr/src/gateway/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:160:13)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1101:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
```

Postman Headers

```
curl -X POST \
  https://gateway.xxx.intra/file \
  -H 'Postman-Token: xxxx3d14-dfee-4c6b-85e1-5592c2e0f9e2' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F 'send_files[]=@C:\Users\xxx\Documents\import_template.xlsx'
```

Browser request Headers are

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryjZxBpNsIzAmLi5Sy
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="demo[]"; filename="import_template.xlsx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet


------WebKitFormBoundaryjZxBpNsIzAmLi5Sy--
```

Comment: What do you get when you output `console.log(event)` in your `onBasicUpload(event)` handler?

Comment: The Content-Type is different. multipart/form-data is correct.

Comment: @DavidR That function is not triggering.

Comment: @KirenSiva Do you receive any error(s) in your console then?

Comment: Only this POST https://gateway.XXX.intra/file 400

Comment: @nologin yes but why this is not multipart/formdata? I did not do any customization

Comment: Let's take care about the error 400 first (bad request). I guess that your "params"-section of the Post-request in the browser is not json formatted.

Comment: Sorry guys, the issue was with http interceptors written inside a custom package. It was converting all the request content type to application/json. Once it is removed everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you make a request to the server and parse the response as JSON, but it’s not JSON.

Comment: let's compare the postman request with the browsers request. Can you share the request from the browser? (right-click - inspect - network ...) Have a look at the body/payload

Comment: I think it is about how the request is prepared in angular. Relevant code about request header and body  would be helpful.

Comment: I don't have any separate code other than this html